# How to debug Ionic app on Android device or emulator using WebStorm?

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, webstorm

How to debug Ionic app on Android emulator (Geny motion or others possibly, no inclination to a specific emulator) or device using WebStorm on Windows?

Comment: ionic run android -l -c  reference http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1030830/Debug-Ionic-Android-Application-On-Mobile-Devices

Comment: But that won't let me debug from within WebStorm, will it?

Comment: WebStorm doesn't support debugging on emulators and devices. Please vote for this feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14781

Comment: Thank you, I've voted now, hope they get on it, VS 2015 has it already and even on iOS devices, I switched to it for now actually, decent IDE!

Comment: What do you want to debug - the **JavaScript** code or **Java** code?

Comment: Javascript code, but as I mentioned earlier, I switched from Webstorm for cross-platform mobile development.

Comment: Now is 2019, any updates on this issue?